# Did the series Alphas end properly?

Tags: ending

I remember watching [Alphas](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1183865/) a while back but I have no idea where I stopped. Now that I see that there are two full seasons available to stream I would like to consider watching it from the beginning. However, I know that it’s been cancelled, so I am wondering if it finished somewhat properly or if it ended in some annoying cliffhanger or as if there was another season to come? As an example, Arrow was cancelled but they tried to finish it properly. I remember that Heroes didn’t end properly but I still would have watched it because it was so good, so any opinions on that are also welcome (if allowed).

I only did a quick search on DuckDuckGo but honestly I am trying to stay away from search engines or even reading similar questions because in the past I have unintentionally come across spoilers! And I really don’t like spoilers, I’m even careful to avoid reading the synopsis or watching trailers of movies I know I am going to watch, like from Marvel, for instance. All I really need is a “yes”, “no”, “somewhat” type of answer, from someone who remembers how the last season ended. If this has already been answered, apologies in advance. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an unresolved cliffhanger ending to the second season.